# type str doesn't define __round__ method error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, typeerror, xgboost

Trying to implement XGBoost to determine the most important variables, I have some error with the arrays.

My complete code is the following

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from numpy import sort
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel


df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
array=df.values
X= array[:,0:330]
Y = array[:,330]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=7)


model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method
```

What can I do?

Comment: it would be great if you could post the entire error message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More than likely some of the labels you have in `y_train` are actually strings instead of numbers.  `sklearn` and `xgboost` don't require the labels to be numeric.

Try checking the types of `y_pred`.

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([type(value) for value in y_pred])
```

---

Here is an example of what I mean with numeric labels

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

# test with numeric labels
x = np.vstack([np.arange(100), np.sort(np.random.normal(10, size=100))]).T
y = np.hstack([np.zeros(50, dtype=int), np.ones(50, dtype=int)])
model = GradientBoostingClassifier()
model.fit(x,y)
model.predict([[10,7]])
# returns an array with a numeric 
array([0])
```

and here with string labels (same `x` data)

```
y = ['a']*50 + ['b']*50
model.fit(x,y)
model.predict([[10,7]])
# returns an array with a string label
array(['a'], dtype='<U1')
```

Both are value labels. However, when you attempt to use `round` on a string variable, you get exactly the error you are seeing.

```
round('a')

TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method
```

Answer (score -1):

Try indicating "value" as an int:

```
predictions = [round(int(value)) for value in y_pred]
```

Worked for me

Comment: Hahaha... round is for decimal numbers. If we convert the str to int() number, why do we need round()????????????????? hah...